# Deleting site feed comments and replies by an administrator

Tags: 2013

Is there any possible way to delete a comment from an user in the newssfeed without searching in Microfeed list? I am the site collection administrator and I want to moderate the newsfeed of the sites directly from the WebPart.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Its possible through Manage Social Data Permission,

Check this [article](http://sharelockpoint.wordpress.com/2013/08/19/remove-user-posts-in-the-newsfeeds-using-social-data-admin-rights/)

Comment: I had already this option checked so that an admin could delete these comments. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

It seems the only way to achieve this is to delete posts in Microfeed list with a System Account user privileges.